# Set receiving delegate in Swift without segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

I read a few posts about working with delegates in Swift, but mostly they advise to call the viewcontroller which receives the delegate with a segue. I am wondering how to do so without a segue, e.g. in a TabBar app. Here is the code for FirstViewController.swift

```
//  FirstViewController.swift

import UIKit

protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSendMessage(message: String)
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: FirstViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate?.didSendMessage("Hello from FirstViewController")
    }

}
```

And here for SecondViewController.swift

```
//  SecondViewController.swift

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var secondSubTitleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // how to set delegate here?
    }

    func didSendMessage(message: String) {
        secondSubTitleLabel.text = message
    }

}
```

How should I set the receiving delegate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is typically not a scenario where a delegate would fit what you are trying to achieve. If you simply want to call some method in SecondViewController from FirstViewController you can get a reference by

```
if let vc = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers[1] as? SecondViewController {
   vc.didSendMessage("hello")
}
```

or you might want to send a NSNotification instead to avoid the tight coupling which is introduced by the above code

In your AppDelegate:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification("ReceivedAppWatchData", object: self, userInfo: theData)
```

In any view controller where you want to recieve the data:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  ...
  // subscribe to notification
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "watchDataReceived:", name: "ReceivedAppWatchData",object: nil)
  ...
}

func watchDataReceived(notif: NSNotification) {
   // handle data
}

deinit {
   // unsubscribe to notifications
   NSNotification.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

This way any view controller can access the data without knowing about each other.

Comment: Maybe I am looking in the wrong direction then. Real life scenario: I receive Apple Watch data in AppDelegate.swift and want to pass these to a UIViewController instance as soon as they come in. The tab bar app is just for testing. I thought that delgates were the way to go, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect an alternative approach

Comment: Thanks. This works in the test application! Still having some issues in the real life app but this approach seems to do what I am asking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your tab bar controller is controlling the view controllers for each tab, so you should set the delegates in the tab bar controller.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let firstVC = viewControllers[0] as! FirstViewController
        let secondVC = viewControllers[1] as! SecondViewController
        firstVC.delegate = secondVC
    }
}
```

This code obviously has some type safety issues and is assuming that `viewControllers[0]` and `viewControllers[1]` are `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` respectively. Also, you should wait to call the delegate method after `viewDidLoad` in this example. The `SecondViewController` may or may not be loaded yet.